# Как получить данные с API яндекса?

Tags: python, api

Я новичок, пытаюсь получить данные с яндекс расписания через API. Вроде как сделал все по документации которую дает яндекс, но все равно запрос не верный. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Мой код:

```
import requests


url = "https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey={my-api-key}&station=596506&transport_types=train&direction=all&departure"
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text)
```

То расписание которое хочу получить - https://voronezhvokzal.ru/raspisanie-poezdov/

Ссылка на документацию яндекса - https://yandex.ru/dev/rasp/doc/reference/schedule-on-station.html#format

Воронеж-1
Код станции 596506

**Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка**

Comment: Спрячь свой API ключ, а лучше сменаи, он у тебя в ссылке захардкоден!

Comment: Вам возвращается какая-то ошибка или что? Как именно вы понимаете, что запрос не верный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу, что у вас параметры некорректно передаются.

У вас в конце урла есть такой фрагмент:

```
&departure
```

Хотя судя по документации должно быть

```
&event=departure
```

Answer (score 1):

Во перпвых  в строке перед ключём появился неправильный символ - {. Его нужно убрать, скорее всего он попал туда при копировании.

Но даже если это сделать yandex выдаёт ответ

```
{"error":{"text":"Неверный ключ \"{f3a6c277-5bcc-48d9-95ed-6373ba1b6fa5}\"","error_code":"v3.0_api-public-hotfix.672d6be90a4248a7d195732940736ce0f93f12da.0_96","request":"http://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=%7Bf3a6c277-5bcc-48d9-95ed-6373ba1b6fa5%7D&station=596506&transport_types=train&direction=all&departure","http_code":400}}.
```

Это говорит что ключ неверный. Нужно получить ключ для работы с сервисами яндекса.  [Подробнее](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/load.html)
`
Скорее всего вы скопировали код с какого - то курса или урока, и не подставили туда свой код. Еще лучше хранить персональные данные в конфигурационном файле

```
f"...api_key={config.api_key} ..."
```

Или в переменных окружения

```
import os

f"...api_key={os.getenv("api_key")) ..."
```

Comment: Это мой ключ который я создал в яндексе для API Яндекс.Расписаний. Вопрос остается открытым..

Comment: Видимо он неправильный или еще не активирован или что то еще. Яндекс возвращает то, что ключ не верный. Дело в настройках вашиго кабинета, или возможно (но крайне маловероятно) на серверах яндекса. Из тех исходных данных, что вы дали найти проблему нельзя. Я думаю что в этой ситуации лучше всего написать в техническую поддержку.